How to check for solutions of non-linear systems over the integers modulo m?
We have the following system of 3 equations and 5 unknowns:
$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
u^2 + w^2 + x^2 + y^2 & = & 0\\
w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 & = & 1 \\
u^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 & = & 2
\end{array}\right.$
Where $u$, $w$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are elements of $\mathbb Z_m$ (the integers modulo $m$).
I've noticed that the existence of solutions to this system depends on the value of $m$. For example, it's easy to check that for $m = 2$ there are no solutions to the system, but if $m = 5$ then there are 16 distinct solutions, like $(u,w,x,y,z) = (0,3,1,0,4)$.
Then I ran a program in C++ that checks for the existence of solutions of the system depending on the value of m up to around 100 and, from what I've gathered, the system seems to only have solutions in $\mathbb Z_m$ if $m$ isn't divisible by 3 or by 4, or if $m \ne 2$. And I say "seems" because I have no idea how I'd even start proving it.
For context, I'm not that well versed in number theory (I only studied a bit about congruences, modular arithmetic and linear diophantine equations on my linear algebra course), but this seemed like an interesting problem and I don't know if there is some theorem or well-known result that helps solve this. Have non-linear systems like this over $\mathbb Z_m$ been studied in-depth? I'd like to see if generalizations of this problem exist.

These sorts of questions are very difficult in general but some very interesting things are known about them. You can start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem and move on to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures.

It's a linear system in $u^2,w^2,x^2,y^2,z^2$, so  you solve for the squares then try to determine which numbers square to those things modulo $m$. Additionally, you can treat $x^2+y^2$ as one variable.

Let's see, lemma, given a prime $p$ and a target $t,$   there always exist $x,y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv t \pmod p.$  This one uses just a counting/pigeonhole argument
This can always be done for any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$   because  each has  a triple of consecutive  quadratic residues, namely  $-1,0,1.$
This can always be done for any prime $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$   because  each has  a triple of consecutive  quadratic residues, namely  $0,1,2.$
It appears that primes $q > 3$  with $q \equiv 3 \pmod 8$   also work, since for each there seems to be always a triple of consecutive residues. This is the kind of thing that Gauss would have worked on; he had some results on clustering of residues.
Anyway, assuming refrences for that idea can be found, your task is easy enough. For example, for prime $q = 11,$   there are residues $3,4,5.$   The sums of pairs of these are $7,8,9.$   So, if we take $x^2 + y^2 = 4$   we then get your three sums as $0,1,2$
For prime $q=  947$  we find consecutive residues $25,26,27$
with pairwise sums $51, 52, 53$  Next, $947 - 51= 896$  So, solve $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 896 \pmod{947}$ to get four-sums $0,1,2$
enough for a start
Plenty of more recent articles with some bearing on triples of consecutive quadratic residues mod a prime.
